# Не устанавливается билд на андроид 5.1

Tags: android

Собственно не могу установить билд на адроид 5.1. Выдает сообщение "приложение не установлено". Проверил на телефоне со старым андроидом (4.1) - билд установился, аппа немного кривая почему-то, правда, но все же установилась и хоть как-то отображается...
В настройка телефона естественно стоит галка "устанавливать из неизвестных источников". Может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Там возможно traget SDK версия ниже 5.1 установлена в манифесте.

Comment: Несколько месяцев назад делал билд ( в среде  Intel XDK) для другой аппы - установился без вопросов на андроид 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал сброс на заводские настройки - аппа установилась.